# Make a div-section appear event based

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input where I enter a small natural number, e.g. 4, and then after hitting enter it creates a special square table (the dimensions are equal to the number entered by the user). After the table there is also a button (which shouldn't be too important for this toy example).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function createTable(num_rows,num_cols,idString)
            {
                var theader = '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">\n';
                var tbody = '';

                for( var i=0; i<num_rows;i++)
                {
                    tbody += '<tr>';
                    for( var j=0; j<num_cols;j++)
                    {
                        tbody += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>';
                    }
                    tbody += '</tr>\n';
                }
                var tfooter = '</table>';
                document.getElementById(idString).innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
            }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Enter Number: <input type="text" name="numberCities" 
      onChange='createTable(this.value,this.value,"costMatrixDiv")'><br>
        Table:
        <div id="tableDiv"></div>
        <button>I am a Dummy-Button!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The **Plunker version**:

https://plnkr.co/edit/DWYEbllT2ynihoTreEDY?p=preview

**What I want:** Before entering a number, the user can see the text "Table:" as well as the Button. However, I want those parts not being present before user input.

**What I don't want:** I don't want to create the text "Table:" as well as the Button in one wish with the matrix through function createTable(...). This would lead to the desired solution for this toy example, but not to the ideal solution for the more complex project I am working on. It would be ideal to create a div-section around "Table:" as well as the Button and to have a technique to make the div-section appear when the user enters a number.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd toy example and hard to give a good answer without knowing what's going on otherwise and why we're writing plain JS, but:

Put `<div id="tableHolder" style="display: none;">` before Table: and `</div>` after `</button>`.

Then in your onchange, you could do:

```
createTable(...); showHolder(this.value);
```

In your script:

```
function showHolder(value) {
  var s = document.getElementById('tableHolder').style;
  var newD =  value%1 == 0 && value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
  if(s.display != newD) {
   s.display = newD
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you - your solution perfectly does what I desire!

Answer (score 1):

So the `createTable` function is returning:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

The 3rd parameter of the `onChange` function on your input is trying to eventually set the innerHTML of whatever is passed to it. So if you change that to `tableDiv`, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="numberCities" onChange='createTable(this.value,this.value,"tableDiv")'>
```

Then it works for me.

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hcu6zo8d/)

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry for that mistake in my code - have simply overlooked it but found it with your help. Thanks!